# rails "NoMethodError in SessionsController#create ". Apparently a nil object I don't expect, or so says the error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, null, nomethoderror

I am trying to sign in users with sessions. My controller has a method 'create' sessions:

```
def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password])

    if user.nil?
        #create an error message and re-render the signin form
        flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
        @title = "Sign in"
        render 'new'
    else
        #sign in user and redirect to the user's show page
        sign_in user
        redirect_to user
    end
end
```

the class method 'authenticate' always returns null. I uses the console to create users where 'nil?' returns false, and then I call 'authenticate' and it returns nil, everytime. I don't know why and have pored over it for hours. At first I thought it was the way I was passing the parameters to the authenticate method, but those should be right, and since the auth method doesn't even work in console with regular values it probably isnt the parameters but the structure of 'authenticate'. Here is the 'authenticate' method and its helper methods:

```
#defining a class method for "User" to authenticate a user who submits an email and password
def User.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
 user = find_by_email(email)
 return nil  if user.nil?
 return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
end 

# Return true if the user's password matches the submitted password.
def has_password?(submitted_password)
    encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
end

def self.authenticate_with_salt(id, cookie_salt)
    user =find_by_id(id)
    (user && user.salt == cookie_salt) ? user : nil
end

private
    def encrypt_password
        self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
        self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
    end

    def encrypt(string)
        secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
    end

    def make_salt
        secure_hash("{#Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
    end

    def secure_hash(string)
        Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
    end
```

Anyone know what the deal is? and I am happy to supply anymore information. I searched around for potential solutions, and couldn't find any.

sign_in(user) method and helper methods stuff:

```
module SessionsHelper

def sign_in(user)
    #set cookie permanently
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
    #define "current_user" so it can be used all over the place
    self.current_user = user
end

def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
end

def current_user
    @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
end

def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end

def sign_out
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    @current_user = nil
end

private

    def user_from_remember_token
        User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
    end

    def remember_token
        cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil, nil]
    end
end
```

users_controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
# GET requests are automatically handled by the "show" action.
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = @user.name
end

def new
    @user = User.new
    @title = "Sign up"
end

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        sign_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
        redirect_to @user
    else
        @title = "Sign up"
        render 'new'
    end
end
end
```

Comment: "You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least two problems.

1) Don't look for the `:email` and `:password` in the `:session`. They should be in the `:params` hash, not in the `:session` hash inside `:params`. Since you aren't getting the correct `:email`, you never find the `User` record, so `User.authenticate` always returns nil.

2) `User.authenticate` will return `nil` if the email isn't found. If the email is found, it returns the value of `submitted_password == encrypted_password`. You have three possible return values (nil, true, false), but only two control paths, one for nil (record not found) and one for all other cases, so you log the user in regardless of the password test result.

Comment: ok thanks, I will try messing with the params and see what happens

Comment: @Fred, using `params[:email], params[:password]` has stopped me from getting an error message but it never signs a user in, even with correct login stuff. I restarted the server and its still a no go. It seems to be working on the console though.

Comment: Look at sign_in(user) and see if it is doing the correct thing. Also, unless you just want to write the authentication code, the Devise gem contains a nice authentication engine for Rails.

Comment: sign_in(user) works when a user signs up though. here is its code: `def sign_in(user)
  #set cookie permanently
  cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
  #define "current_user" so it can be used all over the place
  self.current_user = user
 end`

Comment: sorry the code looks terrible. I'll put it in the original post

Comment: What is the value of `self` in sign_in? If sign_in is defined in the controller, self will be the current controller instance, and that will go away at the end of processing the request.  You need to put current_user someplace where it survives requests.    I suspect sign_in works for signups because you render after sign_in rather than redirect. Am I right?

Comment: sorry I didn't include sign_in helper methods. I saved current_user in an instance variable using the cookie token. I included the helpers above in the original post under the sign_in method definition.

Comment: and when a user signs in I still use redirect

Comment: I found it! When using `form_for` to generate the sign in form, I had called the form `:sessions` instead of `:session` so that's why when I was using `params[:session][:email]` it was giving me a nil object error. I appreciate all the effort you put in to helping me. thank you